# How to reload the page one time using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I want to reload my page after all my code is loaded without using a button.

I used: `location.reload();`

The problem is that it repeatedly reloads my page all time.

Comment: Why? Smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Even if you do it after your page has finished loading it will still reload in a loop .. at what point do you want it to *stop* reloading?

Comment: This is one of those questions where we _really_ would like to know what you're trying to accomplish, so we can suggest a solution.

Comment: So you want your page to load, and once it does, to reload the page, so that it all loads again?

Comment: @Explosion Pills : exactly like a loop, I want to execute this function just one time after my page loaded totally.

Comment: @SlimMils: Why does it reload the page?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store some sort of state outside of the page's JavaScript that will indicate whether or not to refresh. One way is to use [`localStorage`](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), or a cookie, but neither of these will work per-tab or per-window.

Comment: A more detailed answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Your `window.reload()` is getting hit every time the page is reloaded. Do something like this:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('?reloaded') === -1) window.location.href = window.location.href + "?reloaded=true";
```

This assumes that the page isn't using any other url parameters.

**EDIT**

As Matt Ball pointed out, using localStorage or cookies won't be restrictive to a single tab or window, but as Jackson Sandland pointed out in the comments, my above-given solution will alter the browser history. After doing some digging I came up with another, admittedly "hacky" but seemingly effective solution: Using `window.name` instead of a flag in the URL:

```
if(window.name !== "refreshed") {
    window.name = "refreshed";
    window.location.refresh();
}
```

If you'd like to test this out, paste the following in an HTML file and load it in your browser:

```
<script>
window.name = prompt("Window name", window.name);
</script>
```

Enter a new name, then refresh the page. You'll see that on refresh the new name is displayed. Similarly, if you then open a second tab with the same file, you can set the name for that tab independently of the other.

Comment: Not ideal. You are appending the URL. This effects browser navigation.

Comment: I agree, @Jackson_Sandland. Happily, in my many years of development I've seldom seen a problem that couldn't be solved in a better way than doing something like the OP is requesting. If you've ended up here, perhaps there is a better solution (than refreshing) to your problem as well.

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland I did some digging and found another hack. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to flag somewhere that it has been reloaded once.
Using cookies or localStorage as said by Matt, if you need per-tab you can change the location.hash

Maybe you can help us understand WHY you want to reload, there could be another way.